# i tried to remove pushpins from bingmaps but when i zoom in or zoom out or grag the map, the removed pushpin appears again

Tags: asp.net, bing-maps

I have a created a bing map and i have got success in adding and remove the pushpins but after removing the pins if i zoom in/zoom out or drag the map, the removed pushpins appears again

***Here is my code***

```
            var arr = new Array();
            arr = $('div[id*=Contractor]');
            $.each(arr, function (index, value) {
                var v = $(value).find("div[id^='distance']").text().substr(10, $(value).find("div[id^='distance']").text().indexOf('km') - 10);
                if (v > 50) {
                    i = value.id.substr(10);
                    $.each(contractorPushpinObjectArray, function (index, value) {
                        if (contractorPushpinObjectArray[index][0] == i) {
                            map.entities.remove(contractorPushpinObjectArray[index][1]);
                            cid.push(i);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: I have searched for this issue. Bing maps is based on layers what i have done wrong is i have creating multiple layers on bing map but tries to remove it from map.entities collection that is why when ever any event occurs, all the removed pushpins appears again

Answer (score 0):

How are you adding the pushpins to the map? If you are using some sort of clustering tool you will need to remove the pins from the clustering tool otherwise the next time the clustering algorithm runs it will read the pushpins.